# What is the difference between the Superman and the Ultimateman?

Tags: nietzsche

In **Nietzsche's** words :

> Man is something that shall be overcome. Man is a rope tied between
>   beast and superman - a rope over an abyss.

Although the concept of the **superman** is well documented, there's a reference to another type of **man** in **Nietzsche's** most famous book (*Also sprach Zarathustra: Ein Buch für Alle und Keinen*) the **¡ultimateman!**

What is the main difference between the two?

Comment: With "ultimateman" do you mean the [Last Man (German: Letzter Mensch)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_man) ?

Comment: "I love those that know not how to live except as down-goers, for they are the over-goers. " ?

Comment: I mean literally the ultimate man! "Give us this Ultimate Man, O Zarathustra' (Pag.47, Penguin Classics) and @MauroALLEGRANZA Why did you removed the metaphysics tag? This question is all about metaphysics!

Comment: i think it's a good question that gets to the nub of 'nihilism' for today... maybe a d&g answer?

Comment: What's a d&g answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Superman, Ultimate man, Overman are just different names to describe the same concept, so there is no difference between the two!

Comment: I suspect that is true, but would you have any reference to justify the answer?

Comment: The ultimate man is only called once in Zarathustra's book, "Give us this Ultimate Man, O Zarathustra", The Ultimate Man is just an apostrophe to the Superman, to be precise to any kind of Overman!

Comment: it is *certainly no*t the overman that they mean!! @FrankHubeny